Unity project - xcode 13 Undefined symbol error
I have a problem. I've been trying for a long time
I made a game with Unity and it is available on Googleplay.  There is no problem on the Android side.  Everything works smoothly, including Admob and in-app purchases.
Now I want to publish it on Appstore.
I have an old macbook.  The highest version supports Xcode 13.0.  I am trying to prepare the project for iOS with Xcode 13.0
It gives the following error.
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initWithURL:resolvingAgainstBaseURL:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$queryItems
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initWithBytes:length:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initMessageInfoFn
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$copyMessageInfoFn
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$showWithCompletionHandler:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initWithConsentFormClientReference:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isConsentFormAvailable
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initWithConsentInformationClientReference:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$adSourceInstanceName
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$adSourceName
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$extrasDictionary
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$responseIdentifier
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$adNetworkClassName
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$loadWithAdUnitID:orientation:request:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setCustomAdPosition:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setAdPosition:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setExtraWithKey:value:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$adNetworkExtrasWithDictionary:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setCustomRewardString:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setUserIdentifier:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$addKeyword:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maxAdContentRating
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setMaxAdContentRating:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$tagForUnderAgeOfConsent:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$tagForChildDirectedTreatment:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$sameAppKeyEnabled
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setSameAppKeyEnabled:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$heightInPixels
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setDidEarnRewardCallback:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setAdFailedCallback:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setDidDismissCallback:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setAdImpressionCallback:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$show
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setAdClickedCallback:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setAdLoadedCallback:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setAdFailedToLoadCallback:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setPaidEventCallback:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setAdFailedToPresentFullScreenContentCallback:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setAdWillPresentFullScreenContentCallback:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initWithRewardedInterstitialAdClientReference:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initWithSmartBannerSizeAndBannerClientReference:adUnitID:adPosition:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initWithBannerClientReference:adUnitID:width:height:adPosition:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initWithAppOpenAdClientReference:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setPauseOnBackground:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setApplicationMuted:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$state
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$gadu_referenceKey
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$startWithCompletionHandler:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$environment
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$indexOfObject:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$price
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$priceLocale
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$transactionID
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$originalTransactionID
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isIntroductoryOffer
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setDateFormat:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$dateFromString:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$compare:options:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$pathExtension
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$stringByAppendingPathExtension:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initFileURLWithPath:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maxParametersPerFilter
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maxFiltersPerAudience
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$timeIntervalSinceDate:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$adapterStatusesByClassName
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$compare:options:range:locale:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isValidInternalEventParameterName:failureCode:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$sortedArrayUsingComparator:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$itemScopedCustomParameterEnabled
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maxItemScopedCustomParameters
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isValidArrayParamItem:failureCode:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setCenter:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$safeAreaLayoutGuide
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$layoutFrame
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setAppOpenAd:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$appOpenAd
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$loadWithAdUnitID:request:orientation:completionHandler:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setRewardedInterstitialAd:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$rewardedInterstitialAd
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$rewardedInterstitialAdClient
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setAdditionalParameters:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$interstitialClient
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$adDidDismissFullScreenContentCallback
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$pauseOnBackground
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$adWillPresentFullScreenContentCallback
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$adFailedToPresentFullScreenContentCallback
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$adReward
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$rewardedAd
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$presentFromRootViewController:userDidEarnRewardHandler:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setFullScreenContentDelegate:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$adLoadedCallback
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setTagForChildDirectedTreatment:
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$rewardedAdClient
Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$adImpressionCallback

I asked artificial intelligence. I tried the suggestions

what libraries are you linking against?

İ dont understand. Libraries ? Linking ?
